# what is entity reference definition

Tags: c#, entity, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, entityreference

I'm trying to understand the use of entity reference (in crm 2011) I found online many examples of entity reference use, mostly with lookup fields, but I need an absoulte descreption. Is entity reference only for lookup field use ? can I use a simple entity to get my data? can entity replace entity reference ? 
My quesrion is not only about the difference between entityreference and entity it also about the definition of entityreference and why/where to use it.
Can someone make this subject clear please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert EntityReference to Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277597/convert-entityreference-to-entity)

Comment: @ArunVinoth I saw that answer before I posted my question and it wasn't clear enough, I don't think my question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Dynamics CRM development records are called entities and are made up of attributes. When an attribute is a lookup (i.e., a reference to another entity) it is of type `EntityReference`. The `EntityReference` type is necessary because it must convey both the logical name of the entity and the `id` (a `Guid`) of the specific record.

```
    IOrganizationService service = GetService(); //TODO: Implement GetService()

//From: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328149.aspx

Entity contact = new Entity("contact");
contact.Attributes["firstname"] = "ContactFirstName";
contact.Attributes["lastname"] = "ContactLastName";
Guid contactId = service.Create(contact);

Entity account = new Entity("account");
account["name"] = "Test Account1";
EntityReference primaryContactId = new EntityReference("contact", contactId);
account["primarycontactid"] = primaryContactId;
```

An `Entity` object cannot be used as an `EntityReference` because of the type difference. There is a method on `Entity` that returns an `EntityReference`, `Entity.ToEntityReference()`.

**IMPORTANT**

The crucial thing about the `EntityReference` is that it contains both the *logical name* and the *id* of the record.

There are several areas in Dynamics CRM, such as when the Customer datatype is used, where a Lookup may refer to more than one entity type. In these situations there is no way for Dynamics CRM to rely on just a `Guid` as the record identifier.